# jSON formatting error with date format

Tags: php, json, database, date

Hey I'm using this code to get data from my db:

```
  dt_amm_offerte: function(){
        if($('#dt_amm_offerte').length) {

            var oTable;

            oTable = $('#dt_amm_offerte').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_alt",
                                    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'<'dt_actions'>l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
                "sAjaxSource": "async/datatable/amm_offerte.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false },
                    { "bSortable": false }          
                ],
                                    "oLanguage": {
                                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                                        "sUrl": "lib/datatables/lang/dataTables.italian.txt"
                                    }
            } );   
        } 
    },
```

The part of code that pushing data in is  async/datatable/amm_offerte.php

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
  switch ($i) {
    case 0: 
        $row[] = '<label><input class="check" value="'.$aRow["id_offerta"].'" name="azioni[]" type="checkbox" ></label>';
        break;
    case 1: 
        $row[] = $strong."<a href='".URL."amm-aggiungi-offerta?id=".$aRow["id_offerta"]."'>".$aRow["titolo"]."</a>".$strong_close;
        break;
    case 2: 
        $row[] = $strong.$aRow["autore"].$strong_close;
        break;
    case 3: 
        $row[] = $strong.$aRow["negozio"].$strong_close;
        break;
    case 4: 
        $row[] = $strong.get_stato($aRow["stato"]).$strong_close;
        break;
    case 5: 
        $row[] = $strong.$aRow["click"].$strong_close;
        break;
     case 6: 
        $row[] = $strong.$aRow["data_inserimento"].$strong_close;
        break;
     case 7: 
        $row[] = $strong.$aRow["data_aggiornamento"].$strong_close;
        break;
  }
}
```

It works correctly but I need to change my date format type from
2018-01-24 17:37:04
to 24-01-2018 17:37:04 to be a familiar date , i tried to use

> date_format function

But I get the following error:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'dt_amm_offerte'): DataTables warning:
>   JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON
>   formatting error.

What should I do then?

Comment: Show us the offending JSON

Comment: what is that ? i'm sorry i'm new with JSON